# Wrong fingerprint in Rails 3.1 asset pipeline for JS files in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets

I'm deploying the project to the server after deploying CSS and images - it's working, but the JS doesn't work - 404. JavaScript hash in HTML and public/assets - mismatch.

```
In HTML: application-6851a5d9167871936c32da723dca0f23.js
In public/assets: application-95ecf5bab4b7984abe8c1c23b72a7679.js
```

Comment: Could you add some information to your question (directly by editing it): What does that html means? Do you mean the URL generated by Rails in your source code? I suspect it works in development. What did you do to get the assets? `rake assets:precompile`? Have you changed anything in the configuration? Is that a new rails application or a migrated one?

Comment: yes, i mean the URL generated by Rails in my source code. Yes it works in development, but not worked in production. I get the assets by means of rake assets:precompile. Is that new rails app

Comment: I checked with my applications, there the hash is the same in the HTML code and the file path. Have you checked your `manifest.yml` which contains the fingerprints per file? Which server do you use in production?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run 'rake assets:clean assets:precompile'?

Also, if you're using GIT, you'll need to 'git rm' the older versions of the assets too.  You'll need to do something similar for other version control systems if you Production environment is updated by pushing a workspace (e.g. Heroku).

In your Development environment, Assets are fetched directly from your source base - so if you change them, you don't need to precompile again (saving you time during development).  But, you can stumble on the assets fairly easily because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the app fixed it for me.

E.g. in the app's root directory:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

or in Capistrano 3's *deploy.rb*:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        execute :touch, 'tmp/restart.txt'
      end
    end
  end

  after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
end
```